# Joomla database query based on dropdown selection

Tags: database, forms, dynamic, joomla

I am very new to programing but after a lot of research i can rufly manage to create a dropdown selection from database and  show a column result from that  table based on the dropdown selection using ajax.

I write the html form, the php file that connects to the database, the script that loads the data on the dropdown list, the script that handles the on change event and calls for the php file that queries the database and display the result on a div.

In this particular case is a price stored on the database based on the destination selection.

Now my problem atarts here:

I'm using joomla and i would like to do this with the code that I have but I have no clue where to save the various html, php and js files.

I tried doing this with chronoforms but gave up as I found it very difficult.

Can someone give me some advise on what and how to do this?

Comment: Show what did you tried, this way no one can help you.

Comment: Try looking at this answer, it tells you how to create a minimal joomla component where you can try out your code: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328293/where-to-put-a-simple-callable-php-script-in-joomla-directory/44330398#44330398